# Excel Power Query displaying #DIV/0 when using values

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a CSV uploaded with Power Query in excel and am trying to take the averages of 5 values in a column. All values exist and are not equal to 0 yet both the =AVERAGE() and =SUM() functions return #DIV/0 and 0 respectively.

[=SUM() returning 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOu1q.png)
[=AVERAGE() returning #DIV/0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIu8s.png)

Pasting the values without formatting worked but I want to keep the function over the CSV data as I want the averages to refresh periodically with Power Query.

Is this a problem with Power Query, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: `Trim`, `Promote Headers` & `Change Type` of data is something may be you are missing

Comment: Looks like your numbers are text. Change type for column in power query

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya has the answer. Promote the first row to headers. Change the data type to numerical.  IF you still have issues post the view from powerquery, not the output in excel